# matplotlib plot shows an unnecessary diagonal line

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So I'm trying to plot the approximation of an equation using Euler's method, and it works, the only problem is that the plot shows a diagonal line from the first point to the last, when I use a symbol to plot `'<'`, the line is gone, but I need a continuous line.

```
from decimal import *
#The Decimals are so that x is precise
from matplotlib import pyplot as pyplot

#Creates a range but with floats
def rangoFloat(m,maximo,cre): 
    minimo=Decimal(m)
    n=str(cre)
    while minimo <= maximo:
        yield float(minimo)
        minimo += Decimal(n)

#Substracs xn and delta
def ant(xn,delta): 
    return (float(Decimal(xn)-Decimal(delta)))


#Main function
def Teuler(x0,y0,A,B,cre=0.1,limite=20,delta=5,arr=([],[])): 
    y1=float(y0)
    arr[0].append(x0)
    arr[1].append(y0)
    for i in rangoFloat(ant(x0,-cre),limite,cre):

        arr[0].append(i)
        y1=float(Decimal(y1) * (Decimal(1) + Decimal(cre) * Decimal(A) - Decimal(cre) * Decimal(B)))
        arr[1].append(y1)
        
    return arr
```

When I run the next plots, the diagonal line appears

```
t1=Teuler(0, 1, 0.1, 0.16524,0.1,240)
t01 = Teuler(0, 1, 0.1, 0.16524,0.1,240)
t001=Teuler(0, 1, 0.1, 0.16524,0.01,240)
t0005= Teuler(0, 1, 0.1, 0.16524,0.0005,240)
pyplot.grid()
pyplot.plot(t1[0],t1[1])
pyplot.plot(t01[0], t01[1])
pyplot.plot(t001[0], t001[1])
pyplot.plot(t0005[0], t0005[1])
pyplot.show()
```

I'm using python 3.7

Comment: At first, try to never use mutable types as default parameters (`arr=([],[])`). At second, how do you manage to plot if arrays in `t...` have different length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are using mutable type as default parameter (`([],[])`). What happens is every new function `Teuler` call reuses the same arrays. You can see it by adding `print` statement at the beginning of the `Teuler`:

```
print('arr length: ', len(arr[0]), len(arr[0]))
```

After calling it:

```
t1=Teuler(0, 1, 0.1, 0.16524,0.1,240)
t01 = Teuler(0, 1, 0.1, 0.16524,0.1,240)
t001=Teuler(0, 1, 0.1, 0.16524,0.01,240)
t0005= Teuler(0, 1, 0.1, 0.16524,0.0005,240)
arr length:  0 0
arr length:  2400 2400
arr length:  4800 4800
arr length:  28800 28800
```

So, your `t...` arrays start from beginning multiple times, that's what the diagonal lines give evidence of.
What you need to do is whether pass mutable classes explicitly as arguments or change your code to prevent arrays reusing, e.g.:

```
#Main function
def Teuler(x0,y0,A,B,cre=0.1,limite=20,delta=5,arr=None):
    if arr is None:
        arr = ([],[])
```

For further reading can recommend [Python Anti-Patterns](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html)