# How to eliminate the diagonal line that appears when I run my script using pandas and matplotlib?

Tags: python, plot, graph

I have come across this similar situation: [matplotlib plot shows an unnecessary diagonal line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62704973/matplotlib-plot-shows-an-unnecessary-diagonal-line)  however, it didn't help me since I produce my plot from a csv file, not a data array. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\MPGES-1\Computational_work\MD\rmsd-yeni-utf-modifiye.csv", sep=";")

df.plot(kind="line", color="red", title="rmsd", xlabel="time", ylabel="freq")

plt.plot(df)
plt.show()
```

I attach the graph and the screenshot of the beginning of the csv file.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq07g.png)
[screenshot-csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1wBR.png)

Shortly, I only want to eliminate the diagonal line seen in the picture as the rest of the graph seems to be fine.

Thanks,

Comment: Does removing the `plt.plot(df)` line help?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why you would involve pandas in this at all.  It's trivially easy to read that CSV file by hand and create your X and Y columns to have full control over things.  (The `gnuplot` tool could create this plot with no scripting at all, but that's another story.)

Comment: @MegaIng  it didn't, but thank you.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you for your suggestion. I'm still trying to optimize which graphing methods would work better/easier for me. By "to read that CSV file by hand and create your X and Y columns", you mean creating a data frame and then pass it to a plotting tool in the same Python script? As for the gnuplot, I might try it again in the future. Not good luck with it so far :/

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `read_csv` is inferring a header row from your csv file and is plotting x/y columns incorrectly in your example.

As your csv file does not have a header row you can use set the `names` like below to define one during import and use the column names to plot `x='time', y='freq'`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\MPGES-1\Computational_work\MD\rmsd-yeni-utf-modifiye.csv", sep=";", names=['time', 'freq'])
df.plot(kind="line", color="red", title="rmsd", xlabel="time", ylabel="freq", x='time', y='freq')

plt.show()
```

---

Alternatively you can set `header=None` when reading the csv and use the indexes for plotting `x=0,y=1`

```py
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\MPGES-1\Computational_work\MD\rmsd-yeni-utf-modifiye.csv", sep=";", header=None)
df.plot(kind="line", color="red", title="rmsd", xlabel="time", ylabel="freq",x=0,y=1)
plt.show()
```

---

Or as a third fix you could consider adding a header row to your dataset

[image]

and plot letting pandas use the first row as header for column names

```py
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\MPGES-1\Computational_work\MD\rmsd-yeni-utf-modifiye.csv", sep=";")
df.plot(kind="line", color="red", title="rmsd", xlabel="time", ylabel="freq",x="time",y="freq")
plt.show()
```

---

*example plot using different data*
[image]

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it worked! I tried both adding the row for the names in the beginning of the csv file, and wihtout adding, but using the x=0, y=1 parameters in each case. There's a small visual difference which is not important. Thank you again.